# Can button click event goes to controller instead in javascript

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The click event is in javascipt. Can I make it to be in controller? I want to write in C#, not in Javascript. Here is the code for my button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" onclick="btnAdd_Click" Text="Add" 
                            Width="112px" />
```

Comment: Don't use asp.net webforms controls in MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right your question, you have to use a `Form` tag in your page or via `JQuery.onClick()` send an ajax, post or get, to the controller and from it return a JSON with your data